# Distribution-agnostic package search and installation

Tags: linux, bash, package-management

I'm trying to figure out a distribution-agnostic way to install packages providing specific executables or files. I know that it is impossible to get this perfect, but I think I have something that is almost good enough and I was hoping that maybe someone has an idea on how to improve upon it.

Basically I've written a script that provides an abstraction layer around the most common package managers:

```
commandAvailable() { command -v $1 &> /dev/null; }

if commandAvailable dnf; then
    updatePackageInfo() { dnf check-update; }
    searchPath() { dnf provides $1 2> /dev/null | grep ' : ' | head -1 | cut -d'.' -f1 | rev | cut -d'-' -f 2- | rev; }
    searchBin() { searchPath {/bin,/sbin,/usr/bin/,/usr/sbin}/$1; }
    install() { dnf install -y $@; }
elif commandAvailable yum; then
    updatePackageInfo() { yum check-update; }
    searchPath() { yum provides $1 2> /dev/null | grep ' : ' | head -1 | cut -d'.' -f1 | rev | cut -d'-' -f 2- | rev; }
    searchBin() { searchPath {/bin,/sbin,/usr/bin/,/usr/sbin}/$1; }
    install() { yum install -y $@; }
elif commandAvailable apt-get; then
    updatePackageInfo() { apt-get update && if ! commandAvailable apt-file; then install apt-file; fi && apt-file update; }
    searchPath() { apt-file search $1 | head -1 | cut -d':' -f1; }
    searchBin() { searchPath {/bin,/sbin,/usr/bin/,/usr/sbin}/$1; }
    install() { apt-get install -y $@; }
elif commandAvailable pacman; then
    updatePackageInfo() { pacman -Sy && pacman -Fy; }
    searchPath() { pacman -F $1 | head -1 | rev | cut -d' ' -f2 | rev; }
    searchBin() { pacman -F $1 | grep -B 1 -P "    (usr/bin|usr/sbin|bin|sbin)/$1" | head -1 | cut -d' ' -f1; }
    install() { pacman -S --noconfirm $@; }
elif commandAvailable zypper; then
    updatePackageInfo() { zypper refresh; }
    searchPath() { zypper search -f $1 | grep " | package" | head -1 | tr -d ' ' | cut -d'|' -f2; }
    searchBin() { searchPath {/bin,/sbin,/usr/bin/,/usr/sbin}/$1; }
    install() { zypper --non-interactive install "$@"; }
elif commandAvailable emerge; then
    updatePackageInfo() { emerge-webrsync -v && if ! commandAvailable e-file; then install app-portage/pfl; fi; }
    searchPath() { e-file $1 | grep -P "(\[I\]| \* )" | sed 's/*//g' | sed 's/\[I\]//g' | tr -d ' '; }
    searchBin() { searchPath /usr/bin/$1; searchPath /usr/sbin/$1; searchPath /bin/$1; searchPath /sbin/$1; }
    install() { emerge $@; }
fi

searchBins() { for executable in "$@"; do searchBin $executable; done | tr "\n" " "; echo; }
searchPaths() { for path in "$@"; do searchPath $path; done | tr "\n" " "; echo; }
installPkgWithPath() { install $(searchPath "$1"); }
installPkgsWithPaths() { install $(searchPaths $@); }
installPkgWithExecutable() { install $(searchBin $1); }
installPkgsWithExecutables() { install $(searchBins $@); }
```

The functions it creates can be used like this:

```
updatePackageInfo                                  # Equivalent to apt-get update

installPkgWithPath "curl/curl.h"                   # Installs the package containing the header file curl/curl.h

installPkgsWithPaths "curl/curl.h" "/usr/bin/wget" # Installs multiple packages by file paths

installPkgWithExecutable curl                      # Install the package that provides the `curl` executable

installPkgsWithExecutables curl wget make          # Install all packages required to get these 3 executables
```

This basically works fine on Fedora, RHEL, Debian, Arch, Gentoo, OpenSuse (and many more I would think). But it does not work on Ubuntu for example because Ubuntu doesn't have the required `apt-file` package (unless you enable the `Universe` repository that provides it).
Another thing that doesn't work is installing things like `vlc` in Fedora. On Fedora you would usually enable the `RPM Fusion` repositories for that.
And I'm sure other distributions have similar situations.

What I have considered is maybe adding a `--force` flag that, when set, causes these repositories to be searched and added if needed. But I would hate to end up in a situation where I have to maintain lists of repositories. My hope is that most distributions somehow reference these semi-trusted repositories in a way that I don't have to maintain a list of repositories for every distribution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I guess with Debian's 50,000+ installable packages, I haven't needed to look outside Debian mirrors. The idea you have is kind of cool, but you probably would require repository list updating. Also, you're going to be creating franken distros, and that can really screw things up!

Using various force options is good for getting out of a jam, but not recommended for everday use. You could maybe add a subscript to convert packages using `alien`. The idea lends itself well to consuming all available spare time, without limit

I once pondered a HTML system to hold all Linux documentation in existence. I didn't have to ponder it for long!

Comment: The idea of maintaining a repository list is exactly what this question seems to be asking for. Consider whether you have a clarifying comment (concern) on the Question or a full-fledged answer. Thank you!

Comment: from original question: "But I would hate to end up in a situation where I have to maintain lists of repositories."

Answer (score -1):

I have never looked at this before but it could be a good exercise...

I am an Arch Linux user. I am a GNOME user, too. I know there is a GNOME application store **[1]** and it must be distro-agnostic because Arch provides it, Ubuntu and Fedora as well, etc...

So, looking into `gnome-software` **[2]** dependencies two of them have drawn my attention:

1. PackageKit **[3]**, described as *"A system designed to make installation and updates of packages easier"*
2. AppStream **[4]**, described as *"Provides a standard for creating app stores across distributions"*

I think answer to your question is there or at least they will give you a good starting point where to look in

---

[1] https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Software/
[2] https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/gnome-software/
[3] https://www.freedesktop.org/software/PackageKit/
[4] https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Distributions/AppStream/